# Android keeps disconnecting wifi when the signal is weak/poor

Tags: wi-fi, mobile-data

I've recently bought a pixel 4a 5g phone and I'm running the latest version of Android. I'm really happy with the phone but there's one thing that is really bothering: it will use mobile data when the wifi signal is considered weak/poor.

In the old days there was an "avoid poor quality wifi networks" (or something like that) in the advanced wifi settings which used to control this behavior. However, it seems like that option is gone. Is there any way to tell Android to stop transitioning to mobile data when the wifi signal is weak?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the Wifi advanced settings. There you should find an entry named "**Adaptive Connectivity**".

Disable this entry.

Comment: This option on Android 13 on a Pixel 7 is in Network & Internet settings, not Wi-Fi settings. I couldn't find it at first.